# Append new api data to google sheet

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have various (JSON) api data sources that I'd like to append to a google sheet for analysis - ideally run every hour or two alongside a timestamp.

I have the source formatted and I found how to use triggers in google sheets to make it run every 'x' hours - its the appending bit that I'm struggling with. I'm guessing I need some code to work out where the last used row or column is and add one for the next append?

In terms of the data source and as an example for this I am using this code:
http://blog.fastfedora.com/projects/import-json#ImportJSON and one of my data sources (reddit) is extracted as such:

```
=ImportJSON("http://reddit.com/r/redditdev/about.json", "/data/url,/data/subscribers", "")
```

This gives an output as follows:

```
Subscribers  Url
12114        /r/redditdev/
```

What I'd like the end output to look like:

```
Url            TimeStamp             Subscribers
/r/redditdev/  14/10/2017 11:00:00   12114    
/r/redditdev/  14/10/2017 12:00:00   12118
/r/<others>    x                     y
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a little reddit crawler a little while back. Seems like it would be helpful here: [github](https://github.com/haf-decent/googleDrive/blob/master/reddit.gs)

But to customize it a bit to do exactly what you're looking for:

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "America/Los_Angeles", "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
var subs = json_twoDarray[1][0], //first index is row, second is column
    url = json_twoDarray[1][1];
//Assuming there's a "sheet" variable for the sheet you are logging data to,
//get one past the last row and the first three columns and set the values
sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow + 1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([[url, date, subs]]);
```

I also usually append new data to the top of the spreadsheet so the most recent data is presented first which is usually pretty nice. If you wanted to do that you could change the last line of the snippet above to:

```
sheet.insertRowBefore(2); //Assuming the first row is headers, insert a new second row
sheet.getRange(2,1,1,3).setValues([[url, date, subs]]); //add the data
```

I didn't get a chance to test either of these snippets, but they should work. Let me know if you have any issues.